# How to pass an input type value from client to server in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, query-string

I have seen similar questions before posting mine in here. 
My is a little bit different.

I have a `jQuery` calendar control on the page to select `Date`.

```
Select From Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom"/>
Select To Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerto"/>
```

I have a function to display a calendar control:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepickerfrom").datepicker();
    $("#datepickerto").datepicker();
});
```

I also have a `ASP button server control`

`<asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" OnClick="BtnGetData_Click" Text="Get Error List" />`

In my `code behind` I have a method that is invoked when button is clicked:

```
protected void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dateFrom = Request.QueryString["datepickerfrom"]);
    string dateTo = Request.QueryString["datepickerto"]);
    InputData data = new InputData(dateFrom, dateTo);
    LoadLogErrorData(data);
}
```

Ho can I pass selected input values into the `code behind` method to perform necessary database logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `name` attribute of your inputs and use the values that you expect in your `BtnGetData_Click` event handler:

`Select From Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom" name="datepickerfrom" />
Select To Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerto" name="datepickerto" />`

Also if you use POST form method you should use:

`string dateFrom = Request.Form["datepickerfrom"];
string dateTo = Request.Form["datepickerto"];`

Comment: how to do this in webmethod?  @Vladislav Karamfilov